# WooCommerce [product_categories] shortcode - Missing displayed sub-categories

Tags: wordpress, pagination, woocommerce, arguments, shortcode

I am using WooCommerce plugin in WordPress, and I have added 20 sub-categories in one parent category. When I want to display all the sub-categories in a page using this shortcode:

```
[product_categories number="20" parent="0"]
```

It just retrieves 12 of them with no pagination and doesn't display sub-categories.

Why this is happening? 
How can I increase this limit?

Comment: are you a assign the product to all 20 categories. if not then assign.

Comment: what do you mean? where should I assign it?

Comment: are you added product to all 20 categories

Comment: Thank you all. I didn't assign any product to some of sub-categories.

Answer (score 2):

In **`[product categories]`** WooCommerce shortcode, the argument **`number`** is used to display the number of products in that categories / subcategories and not the number of categories.

And argument **`parent="0"`** will only display top level categories and not subcategories.

**This shortcode is made to display product categories loop**

Reference: [**`[product categories]`** WooCommerce shortcode](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-12)

Answer (score 2):

To show sub categories of category you have to change "parent" attrribute. below are some other fields for shortcode.

```
array(
      'number' => 'null',
      'orderby' => 'title',
      'order' => 'ASC',
      'hide_empty' => '1',
      'parent' => '',
      'ids' => ''
 )

[product_categories number="" orderby="" order"" hide_empty="" parent="0" ids""]
```

The "**number**" field is used to display the number of products categories.
The "**orderby**" field is used to display the order of products categories.
The "**order**" field is used to display the order( ASC / DESC ) of products categories.
The "**hide_empty**" field is used to hide products category not assigned to any product.
The "**parent**" parameter to 0 to only display top level categories.
 
The "**ids**" field is to tell the shortcode which categories to display.

For more info see this [link](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-12)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign product to categories, after that all categories will be display.